# Periodically Run Wordpress Importer using Hosted File [WP Plugin]

Tags: php, import, automation, wordpress

So I have a script that creates a WXR(Wordpress eXtended RSS)/XML file from a data source. Wordpress has a plugin to import WXR files but it requires me to manually go in and select the file. What I want to do is ever hour (or time period I select) have Wordpress Importer run using the file that's hosted on the same site.

Would appreciate any tips or help. The code for the Wordpress Importer may be one option but I don't know how to modify it for this purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if there is a more elegant approach, but what I would do if I were in a hurry would be this:

Take the Wordpress plugin code, and hack it up so you can run it from the [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). This will require a bit of reverse-engineering to figure out what exactly their code is doing. Then, I would set a [`cron`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) job to run every hour (or whatever) and execute that PHP script.

Comment: Actually just found this (https://github.com/tott/WordPress-CLI-Importer) which seems to be exactly what I need unless someone has a more elegant solution? What is a good resource for learning about cron jobs?

Comment: Sorry this is a really dumb question but I can create a cron job through my websites CPanel and it appears I can enter one line for the command. What is the correct format for doing so?

Comment: Ya sorry for the stupid question I could have easily Googled! I'll figure out the rest on my own, thanks for the help you saved me a bunch of time!